# How to build FFMPEG with G.722.1 support

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, build

I  want  to build  FFMPEG with G.722.1 audio decoder for my programs. I read that this codec has its own license, different from LGPL. Does anybody have the experience how to make it?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because , as the ffmpeg tag states: **Only questions about programmatic use of the FFmpeg libraries, API, or tools are on topic. Questions about interactive use of the command line tool should be asked on https://superuser.com/ or https://video.stackexchange.com/**. Please delete this.

Answer (score 0):

Code and how to use:

> https://github.com/traviscross/freeswitch/tree/master/libs/libg722_1
>
> PLEASE NOTE that patented techniques are used in G.722.1, and Polycom is the
> owner of the relevant patents. However, Polycom offers royalty free licences
> to use G.722.1 to anyone who complies with a few simple rules. Just contact them,
> and you should have no problem using G.722.1 without any payment at all (at least
> it was very straightforward for the initial user of this code). You should
> check for any licence conflicts with other code in your application - for example,
> use in a GPL'ed project might be problematic, unless you run the G.722.1 codec as
> a separate process, and your application communicates with it through pipes or
> sockets.

And

> https://github.com/traviscross/freeswitch/blob/master/libs/libg722_1/COPYING
>
> a royalty
> free licence is available from Polycom if certain fairly basic conditions are met. Please contact
> Polycom for their current licence conditions.
> For details of the precise license conditions for the original source code, please consult
> Polycom. Polycom permit licenced users of G.722.1 to base their implementations on the
> reference code, so any valid licencee is permitted to use this library.

So, I cannot insert this code into FFMPEG with GPL/LGPL. But I can use  this code as a separate library under my own license. Plus, Polycom consultation must be too.